# UIAlertController as a common function to access across view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

My app validates data received from different view controllers and shows an alert message using `UIAlertViewController`. It is designed to cater for devices `after IOS8`. So, no need to worry about `UIAlertView` handling.

Currently I have my `alert handler` function (like below) in all the view controllers.

```
//MARK: Alert handler

func alert(info:String) {
    let popUp = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: info, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    popUp.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {alertAction in popUp.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)}))
    self.presentViewController(popUp, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I am just wondering if I can have this function written somewhere once and can be shared across the view controllers.

If I am going to have this function in a shared class, is it ok to pass the ViewController instance to the function every time.

Can someone suggest the best way to do this.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You should write an extension on UIViewController. For information about extensions in swift see here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Swift File.

```
class AlertMaker {
func alert(info:String, viewController: UIViewController) {
    let popUp = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: info, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    popUp.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {alertAction in popUp.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)}))
    viewController.presentViewController(popUp, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Call in your VC:

```
AlertMaker().alert("Info to display", self)
```